# Event reciever on item updated do not start when item is updated trough a workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, event-receivers

When an item is updated maually the event reciever starts and work as expected. But when the item is updated through a SharePoint Designer Workflow, nothing happens. There is nothing about this in the logs.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Actualy according to [sharepoint workflow architecture](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/03/12/sharepoint-workflow-architecture-part-2.aspx)  updates is not commited to database right after activity axecutes.  The actual commitment will be done by WorkBatch service right before the workflow is persisted.
Are you shure that event reciever is not fired at all? And is there any System.Workflow-related event in ULS logs?

Comment: I can't find anything about this in the logs, and it work as it should when I update it manually...

Answer (score 0):

If a list has workflows defined which are set to auto-start, these will always execute before any other 'ItemUpdated' or 'ItemCreated' event receivers by default. It is possible to re-order these in code.

[Execution order of event receivers and workflow on a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3147/execution-order-of-event-receivers-and-workflow-on-a-list)

Comment: I am not sure that this is the problem, because the SPD workflow is connected to another list. Not the one with the event reciever. A workflow on list A updates a listitem on list B. The event reciever is Connected to list B.