# What gets trigged fist List Workflow item added or List Event Receiver ItemAdded.?

Tags: workflow, event-receivers

**Workflow Vs Event Receiver**
I have a list in a site collection called projects. I have a workflow on Item Added and now currently in the process of creating Event Receiver.

I would like to know which actually gets trigged first. Event Receiver or Workflow?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Item Added is an Asynchronous event receiver, so your workflow can run before the event receiver or after as well.

This [Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3147/execution-order-of-event-receivers-and-workflow-on-a-list) is same as yours posted here.

It Says :

- Answer By : Chris O Brien

> If a list has workflows defined which are set to auto-start, these
>   will always execute before any other 'ItemUpdated' or 'ItemCreated'
>   event receivers by default. It is possible to re-order these in code
>   however - I needed to do this once as for some reason I needed a
>   receiver to fire before the workflow did it's processing. To re-order,
>   simply get the SPList.EventReceivers and modify the Sequence property
>   of each one you want to change (and call .Update()).
>
> Remember though, that if someone disables workflow and then configures
>   it again (with auto-start), SharePoint will add the
>   SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver back in as Sequence=1, meaning the
>   re-ordering would need to happen again.
>
> If a list has workflows defined which are set to auto-start, these
>   will always execute before any other 'ItemUpdated' or 'ItemCreated'
>   event receivers by default. It is possible to re-order these in code
>   however - I needed to do this once as for some reason I needed a
>   receiver to fire before the workflow did it's processing. To re-order,
>   simply get the SPList.EventReceivers and modify the Sequence property
>   of each one you want to change (and call .Update()).
>
> Remember though, that if someone disables workflow and then configures
>   it again (with auto-start), SharePoint will add the
>   SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver back in as Sequence=1, meaning the
>   re-ordering would need to happen again.

And If you want the -ed ending events to be executed before the workflow, you should set them as synchronous events and not as asynchronous which is the default value. If so (synchronous), the events will always be executed before the workflow.

Comment: Did your question got solved?