# Execution order of event receivers and workflow on a list Item

Tags: workflow, event-receivers

I have SharePoint list. I have added Event receivers on SharePoint list for ItemAdded event.

Also I have SharePoint designer workflow on same list which triggers on Item created and Item Updated.

I would like to know which actually gets trigger first. Event Receiver or Workflow?

Please explain reason.
also I would like to know if I have ItemUpdated event receiver and Designer workflow for trigger when item get updated.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by [Chris O'Brien - MVP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/166/chris-obrien-mvp)    for [Execution order of event receivers and workflow on a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3147/execution-order-of-event-receivers-and-workflow-on-a-list)

> If a list has workflows defined which are set to auto-start, these will always execute before any other 'ItemUpdated' or 'ItemCreated' event receivers by default. It is possible to re-order these in code however - I needed to do this once as for some reason I needed a receiver to fire before the workflow did it's processing. To re-order, simply get the SPList.EventReceivers and modify the Sequence property of each one you want to change (and call .Update()).
>
> Remember though, that if someone disables workflow and then configures it again (with auto-start), SharePoint will add the SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver back in as Sequence=1, meaning the re-ordering would need to happen again.